# How to graph future X values with sns.regplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame that looks like:

```
    date     count
 0  2018-01  10
 1  2018-02  20
```

And I'm appending additional rows so that the X axis will show beyond the values in the dataset:

```
 2  2018-03  NaN
 3  2018-04  NaN
```

I'm graphing it as:

```
ax = sns.regplot('date', 'count', data=df)
```

However, I cannot seem to get the X axis to continue. It always seems to stop at the last populated value. What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it depends what you want to do. If you simply want to extend x-axis without extending the regression then since regplot returns an axes object you can just do:

```
ax = sns.regplot('date', 'count', data=df)
ax.set_xlim(min(df.date), max(df.date))
```

If you want to actually extend the regression to the plot limits, I suggest you also use matplotlib to set up the plot, and then just call `regplot`. `regplot` has a `truncate` argument, which is `False` by default, so it will extend the regression to the plot limits.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.figure()
plt.xlim(min(df.date), max(df.date))
ax = sns.regplot('date', 'count', data=df)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually wanted the regression line to continue and this works perfectly.